# Core Data rollback to an older model version

Tags: ios, core-data

Say if I had a Core Data model version A and recently added a newer version B with some new entities and attributes in it. I built new features based on them and released it to the App Store. Now for some reason I need to roll back the changes, what's the best way to achieve this? One way I can think of is to add a newer model version (version C) with the most recently added entities and attributes removed with the corresponding code cleanups. Alternatively can I just remove version B and reset version A as the current version? Is Core Data able to migrate back from version B (now gone from the model) to A without problem? Note Core Data's Lightweight Migration worked when I migrated from version A to B since those are simple additions of entities/attributes.

Comment: Not sure about rolling back changes. I might look at setting up a second persistent store with the older model (A). Than you could migrate the original (B) store data into the new (A) store. Once, the migration is complete, you can remove the original upgraded store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make a version C - even if it is identical to version A. You should not be too worried about having many model version (within reason). They do not take up much space for the app, and they don't add much complexity to the code. And if every transition work then Core-data can transition any version to your latest model. It may seem a little strange that a person on Version A model would migrate to B only to transition "back" to C, but that is a small price to pay for simple and effective model migration.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I did a test by setting the current version back to A (without adding C), and Core Data seems to perform Lightweight Migration back to A without problem. Is there any other reason why migrating to C would be a better practice?

Comment: What happens when you you add another version? You want you data migration to be consistent and easy to understand.

Comment: Technically it's not a problem, I can add a new version C' based on A instead of on B. I guess the concern here is more about confusing oneself or other developers in the future?

Comment: Maybe, now I am not sure. I can imagine a situation where then model went A->B->C->A where there is a simple migration for A->B and B->C but C->A transition is not well defined. I don't know.